# Is it possible for an increasing function to tend to zero?

Tags: calculus, limits

I have to plot a graph of a real function $f(x)$ such that
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$$
and for $x\geq3$, $f$ increases ($x=3$ is supposed to be the minimum point of $f$).

So, is it even possible? For me, since $f$ increases, then
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty\neq0$$

Comment: $-e^{-x}$ is a strictly increasing function that tends to $0$.

Comment: Just make $f(x)$ have negative values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other people have given explicit examples, but I wanted to explain what is wrong with the reasoning that

> Since $f$ increases, then $$ \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty \, .$$

Consider the function $f$ defined by
$$
f(x)=-\frac{1}{x} \, ,x>0\, .
$$
This doesn't satisfy your requirement of having a minimum at $x=3$, but notice that the function is strictly increasing. As $x$ gets larger, $f(x)$ gets closer and closer to $0$, but does not ever reach it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $f(3)$ can be negative.

About your final "So ...": an increasing function can be bounded. Consider $1-e^{-x}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=-\frac1{x^2-6x+10}$$ has a single minimum at $x=3$ and tends to $0$.